# Задвоенный SQL запрос Django

Tags: sql, django, requests

До редактирования вопрсо стоял так - "Подскажите, как правильно организовать данный код, что бы не было повторяющегося запроса." В комментарии ниже был дан ответ. Вроде мне стало ясно, что первый запрос `SELECT ••• FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = '1' LIMIT 21` отвечает за залогиненного юзера (если я разлогинюсь, то он пропадает), а второй такой же, появляется когда я пытаюсь вытащить автора поста в шаблоне, средством `post.user`. В связи с этим, появилась еще пара вопросов.

1. Почему когда я вызываю в шаблоне `post.title`, джаго не генерит каждый раз запрос в бд в отличии от `post.user`? (потому что второй берется из связанной модели?)
2. Если я создам подобным образом к примеру 100 постов (даже с одним и тем же автором), то при каждом обращении к `post.user` у меня в дебаг тулбаре будет 100 одинаковых запросов типа `SELECT ••• FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = '1' LIMIT 21`. Норма ли это?

models.py

```
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'posts': posts}
    
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

html

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.user }}
{% endfor %}
```

debug_toolbar
[image: debug_toolbar]

Comment: Думаю, в данном конкретном случае избавляться от повторяющегося запроса просто нет смысла. Если вы залогинитесь в другого пользователя или пост будет связан с другим пользователем — запросы станут отличаться

Answer (score 0):

1. Потому что `post.user` ссылается на другую модель (является внешним ключом), а `post.title` - нет
2. Нет, не норма. Для предотвращения подобного поведения в django придумали [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)